# Destructuring nested object having null value cause "TypeError: cannot read property 'obj2' of null"

Tags: javascript, null, destructuring

I try destructuring nested object having null value, but it cause "TypeError: cannot read property 'obj2' of null".

I read about fixing it, but it works on not nested elements.

Take a look at code snippet.

```js
const tmp = { obj: null };

let { obj: { obj2 } = {} } = tmp || {};
```

I expect destructure object and obj2 to be null or undefined, but it cause error :(

It works good when I have "undefined" instead of "null", but I need case with "null".

Answer (score 3):

ES6 destructuring default values only work if the attribute is `undefined`. In any other case it will get the value passed assigned. Even the Javascript falsy values.

A way to circumvent that is to shortcut the possible falsy values, in this case `obj` that is going to be `null`.

```js
const tmp = { obj: null };

const { obj } = tmp;

const { obj2 = {} } = obj || {};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with destructuring. Simply put, like deafult functin parameters, default destructuring values are only applied if the value is undefined, not null or other falsey values.

As an alternative, you could do:

```js
const tmp = { obj: null };
let obj2 = tmp && tmp.obj && tmp.obj.obj2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys @Dez @junvar

I change my code to sth like:

```
const tmp = { obj: null };
const obj2 = tmp?.obj?.obj2;
console.log(obj2);
```